# How to Batch convert blend file and output as fbx files?

Tags: python, export, import, blend-files

I have dozen blender models (1000 of them), and I wish to convert them automatically into individual fbx or obj file, how do I do just that? None of the code I searched on Google is working and I m pretty terrible at coding. Please help a brother out thank you!

Im a beginer and If possible truly wish there is an one-click solution, a seperate blend file would be nice! Thank you in advance.

[image]

I copied this code and it works so far.
But This code cannot filter the remaining fbx file inside the folder, the code will detect error and not run if there is any other fbx inside, need some help please!
Thank you

---

```
    CONVERT_DIR = "E:\\TEST"

    import os

    def file_iter(path, ext):
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
            for filename in filenames:
                ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
                if ext.lower().endswith(ext):
            yield os.path.join(dirpath, filename)

    import bpy


    def reset_blend():
        bpy.ops.wm.read_factory_settings(use_empty=True)

    def convert_recursive(base_path):
        for filepath_src in file_iter(base_path, ".blend"):
            filepath_dst = os.path.splitext(filepath_src)[0] + ".fbx"
    
    print("Converting %r -> %r" % (filepath_src, filepath_dst))
    
    reset_blend()

    bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=filepath_src)
    bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(filepath=filepath_dst)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        convert_recursive(CONVERT_DIR)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a start where the script will take a list of blend files (supplied on the command line) and open each in turn.  You'll then want to add fbx export code fragments that you'll find in other blender.stackexchange python searches:

```
import bpy
import argparse
import sys

def main():
        print('hello')

        # get the args passed to blender after "--", all of which are ignored by
        # blender so scripts may receive their own arguments
        argv = sys.argv

        if "--" not in argv:
            argv = ["-dC:/tmp/blenderOut.txt"]  # as if no args are passed
        else:
            argv = argv[argv.index("--") + 1:]  # get all args after "--"

        # When --help or no args are given, print this help
        usage_text = (
            "blender --background -- *.blend"
        )
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=usage_text )
        parser.add_argument("-d", "--dest", dest="dest_path", metavar='FILE', required=Fals
                        help="Save the generated file to the specified path")
        args = parser.parse_args(argv)

        for f in args.files:
            print(f)
            bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=f)
            # add export code here:
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried ur code and use other code to make it work now! Very appreciate ur help man! Now the thing is this code cannot filter the remaining fbx file inside the folder, the code will detect error and not run if there is any other fbx inside, need some help please! Thank you